# my function does not replace "." with " " and it does not display the array as it should

Tags: c++

I am attempting to display a two-dimensional array retrieved from a file, but it will not display it correctly. It also will not switch the elements from a period to a space right after the file is read into the 2D array.

i am just trying to cout a blank field to the screen and be able to load more fields using the getField function.

``````````````````````````````````````````````````
C++
    class Field
    {
    private: string  xy[20][50];

    public:
        Field() {}

        void getField(string name)
        {
            ifstream file;
            file.open(name);
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
                {//periods should be changed to spaces
                    file >> xy[x][y];
                    if (xy[x][y] == ".")
                    {
                        xy[x][y] = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
            file.close();
        }
        //displaying field
        void display()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
                {
                    cout << xy[x][y];
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        Field field1;
        field1.getField("field1.txt.txt");
        field1.display();
        system("pause");

    }
`````````````````````````````````````````````````
the txt file is pretty much this 20 times:

    |................................................|
``````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You forgot to include your code that isn't working. When adding it, be sure to remove all the completely unrelated parts and pay attention to how to format code here on Stack Overflow, so people can read it more easily and answer faster. Good luck with solving your problem!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How do you think we can answer your question? We can't see your code from where we are! Please post a [mcve] showing the problem you have encountered.

Comment: Before posting any code, give [mcve] a read. That link describes the gold standard for code posted to questions, but even better, it is an amazing debugging technique. If you follow the link's instructions you'll find that more often than not you won't have to ask the question. You'll get part way into making the MCVE and figure it out yourself. Doesn't get much better than that.

Comment: New to the site so if I'm missing anything or syntax is wrong just let me know. I didn't know how to post a question on here so I posted it without code and it got instantly downvoted :/.

Comment: @shoe *the txt file is pretty much this 20 times:* -- How could it look like that when your loop that outputs clearly puts an `std::endl` for each string?  Second, you did no check to see if the file was actually opened successfully.  Since we do not have this file, we cannot assume from your code that anything will work correctly since you don't have a check for the file being opened successfully.

Comment: Are you sure the file is named "field1.txt.txt" ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Exactly, that's the only way it's displaying with the correct shape. It's just that it displays std::endl after the entire loop many times.

Comment: @MuhammedGül Yes it is supposed to be like that haha. I forgot that .txt was atutomatically added to the end of the file name.

Comment: @shoe `file >> xy[x][y];`  -- Realize that reads in an entire string, not just one character.  Your array probably should have been `char xy[20][50]`, not a 2d array of `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're absolutely right! Thank you so much and Sorry for the noobie question

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this:

`private: string  xy[20][50];`

Then you do this, expecting that each character is read into each of the elements of the array:

`file >> xy[x][y];`

The problem is that since the `xy` array is of type `std::string`, the entire string is read into `xy[x][y]`, not an individual character.

What you probably want is this:

`private: char xy[20][50];`

Then the other change would be this:

```
  file >> xy[x][y];
  if (xy[x][y] == '.')
  {
      xy[x][y] = ' ';
  }
```

---

Just a note -- you could read the entire contents into the array first without checking whether the character is a `.`, and at the end, replace using [std::replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...read everything first
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
      file >> xy[x][y];
}

// now replace 
std::replace(&xy[0][0], &xy[0][0] + sizeof(xy), '.', ' ');
```